# How do I include a discussion icon on my page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

How do I include a discussion icon on my page?

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a new Facebook application, and then add it to your page.  You also have to host the content for your page on a webserver somewhere online (not Facebook).  In the settings for your application, you can upload a 16x16 pixel icon.

Follow these steps:

1. create a webpage hosted on your website (e.g. http://mywebsite/fb/discussion.html)
2. go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps
3. click on "+Create New App" (upper right corner)
4. Name your app, something like "My Page Discussion Tab"
5. Check "agree to the Facebook Terms", click through the following dialogs, until:
6. On the application page, click 'edit icon' and upload a 16x16 pixel icon
7. Under "Select how your app integrates with Facebook" select "Page Tab"
8. Under Page Tab Name put 'Discussion' (or whatever you want to name your tab).
9. Under Page Tab URL put the url of your hosted content (e.g. http://mywebsite/fb/discussion.html )
10. Under Secure Page Tab URL put an https version of your hosted content (try the same url, but with https)
11. Click Save Changes
12. On the left, find and follow the link "View App Profile Page"
13. On the App Profile Page, click "Add to My Page"
14. In the popup window, select the Facebook Page you want to have your discussion tab.
15. Close
16. Go to the page you admin, and there is now a discussion tab on the left, with your icon!
17. Yay!

Comment: You could try a free guestbook site (e.g. Guestbook Central), and use the url for your free guestbook as your Page Tab URL.